# Have dnsmasq resolve names from dhcpd

Tags: linux, networking, dns, dhcp

On an Arch Linux server, I am running `dhcpd` with a configuration that gives both dynamic and static leases. This works fine, but using IP addresses is not too nice, especially when addressing dynamic leases.

On that same server, I also have a running instance of `dnsmasq` that handles DNS requests for all machines on the networks it is listening to.

As `dhcpd` has `client-hostname` values from dynamic lease clients and also `host-name` from static leases, I'm wondering if it is possible to let `dnsmasq` know of those names when a client asks for them.

I tried looking in both services documentation but nothing obvious came up, short of turning off `dhcpd` and letting `dnsmasq` handle both DHCP and DNS but I'd rather avoid this.

Thanks for your help